# Как сделать погрузку контента по нажатию кнопки на php?

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователю было видно определённое кол-во контента, но по нажатию на кнопку, кол-во контента увеличивалось на чистом php (я знаю, что можно реализовать на Ajax, но нужно именно на чистом php)

Comment: "кнопку нажать на php" не получится

Comment: php технически не имеет никакого отношения к пользователю, так что это невозможно, только ajax

Comment: Да, я понял, спасибо, а жаль(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без перезагрузки - это не возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте Submit button с action на php

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="text">
<button type="submit" class="send">Submit</button>
</form>
```

только так !